# DevExpress TcxGridDBLayoutViewItem OngetContentStyle doesn't work

Tags: delphi, styles, devexpress

I use `Devexpress` and `Delphi xe7`,

I try to change style of `TcxGridDBLayoutViewItem` differently.

```
  if AItem.EditValue = 'Discharge' then
  begin
    AStyle := cxstylNewDischarge;
  end
  else
  if AItem.EditValue = 'Operation' then
  begin
    AStyle := cxstylNewOperation;
  end
  else if AItem.EditValue = 'Admission' then
  begin
    AStyle := cxstylNewAdmission;
  end
  else if AItem.EditValue = 'Transfer' then
  begin
    AStyle := cxstylNewAdmission;
  end
  else
  begin
    AStyle := cxstylNewNormal;
  end;
```

But when I use this code, all the style of item is changed to just One style, even though the `AItem.EditValue` are different from each other.

Moreover, when I click or mouse over these items, the style is changed automatically.

How can I fix this code?

Comment: Where are you putting this code? I just made a quick test using the `cxGrid` `onGetItemStyle` event handler to control the style assignment based on the `editValue` and it works. I tested this on `Delphi XE5` with `devExpress 13.2.3`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test de ARecord Param. I think the AItem represents de Item (column) and not the value of the record you're testing.

Do this and you shoud be fine:

```
//You can test if the Value is not null before the conditions, or use
//VarToStr (on unit Variants)
AStyle := cxstylNewNormal;
if ARecord.Values[AItem.Index] = 'Discharge' then
    AStyle := cxstylNewDischarge
else
if ARecord.Values[AItem.Index] = 'Operation' then
    AStyle := cxstylNewOperation
else 
if ARecord.Values[AItem.Index] = 'Admission' then
    AStyle := cxstylNewAdmission
else 
if ARecord.Values[AItem.Index] = 'Transfer' then
    AStyle := cxstylNewAdmission;
end;
```